# How to handle different events inside ViewPager Tab?

Tags: android, android-listview, event-handling, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I am working on an android project that contains a view pager. The UI of MenuActivity is as following...

[image: Snapshot of MenuActivity]

Below are the code of view pager activities...

MenuActivity.java

```
public class MenuActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;    
//  Tab titles
private String[] tabs;
private String[] category_id;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);     
    CommonFunctions.changeActionBar(getResources(),getActionBar());
    //  Initialization
    initializeFoodCatagories();
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabs, category_id, MenuActivity.this);     
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);                
        }
    });     
    //Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
}   
private void initializeFoodCatagories() {
    GeneralHelper helper = new GeneralHelper();
    JSONObject json = helper.callWebService(getString(R.string.API_END_POINT) + "get_food_category");
    String total_items = helper.getValueFromJson(json, "TotalRecords");

    tabs = new String[Integer.parseInt(total_items)];       
    category_id = new String[Integer.parseInt(total_items)];

    if(!(total_items.equals("0"))) {
        try {
            final JSONArray jsonarray = json.getJSONArray("Response");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                 JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);                     
                 tabs[i] = jsonobject.getString("category_name").toString();                                                             
                 category_id[i] = jsonobject.getString("category_id").toString();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }       
}
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {      
}
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {        
}
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
}}
```

TabsPagerAdapter.java

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
String [] category_name;    
String [] category_id;
Activity context;   
public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String[] category_name, String[] category_id, Activity context) {
    super(fm);
    this.category_name = category_name;
    this.category_id = category_id;
    this.context = context;
}     
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    for(int i = 0; i < category_name.length; i++) {
        if(index==i) { 
            return new SwipeTabFragment(context, category_id[i]);                                                                           
        }
    }       
    return null;
} 
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return category_name.length;
}}
```

SwipeTabFragment.java

```
public class SwipeTabFragment extends Fragment {
Activity context;   
ListView list;
private String[] item_name;
private String[] price_per_unit;
private String[] item_image;
private String category_id;
public SwipeTabFragment(Activity context, String category_id) {
    this.context = context;
    this.category_id = category_id;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_items, container, false); 
    list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lstItems);
    initializeFoodItems(category_id);
    list.setAdapter(new ItemListAdapter(context, item_name, price_per_unit));
    //ListView event handling
    //This event not working
    /*list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","ListView activated");
        }
    });*/   
    //This event is also not working
    /*rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgPlus).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","Plus Image Button activated");                
        }
    });*/
    return rootView;        
}       
private void initializeFoodItems(String position) {
    String url = getString(R.string.API_END_POINT) + "get_menu_items?food_cat_id="+position;

    GeneralHelper helper = new GeneralHelper();
    JSONObject json = helper.callWebService(url);

    String total_items = helper.getValueFromJson(json, "TotalRecords");
    price_per_unit = new String[Integer.parseInt(total_items)];
    item_name = new String[Integer.parseInt(total_items)];
    item_image = new String[Integer.parseInt(total_items)];


    if(!(total_items.equals("0"))) {
        try {
            final JSONArray jsonarray = json.getJSONArray("Response");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                 JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                 price_per_unit[i] = jsonobject.getString("price_per_unit").toString();
                 item_name[i] = jsonobject.getString("item_name").toString();                                        
                 item_image[i] = jsonobject.getString("item_image").toString();                  
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }       
}}
```

ItemListAdapter.java

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> { 
static int grand_total;
private final Activity context; 
private final String title[];
private final String price[];
private final String discount[];    
public ItemListAdapter(Activity context, String[] title, String[] price,     String[] discount) {
    super(context, R.layout.item_list, title);
    this.context = context;
    this.title = title;
    this.price = price;
    this.discount = discount;
}       
@SuppressLint({ "ViewHolder", "InflateParams" })
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    final View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null,true);       
    ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitl)).setText(title[position]);
   final int item_price = Integer.parseInt(price[position]);
   ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice)).setText(price[position] + " Rs. Each");
    ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtDiscount)).setText(discount[position] + "%");
    RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) row.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
 stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(row.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange),     PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);         
    //Increasing Quantity
    row.findViewById(R.id.imgPlus).setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView qty = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
        qty.setText(String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString()))+1));
        if (Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString()) > 0) {               
            //Calculating Total Amount
            int t = item_price * Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString());
            ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTotal)).setText("Rs. " + String.valueOf(t));                   
        }
    }
    });     
    //Decreasing Quantity       
    row.findViewById(R.id.imgMinus).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView qty = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
        if (Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString()) > 0) {                   
            qty.setText(String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString()))-1));
            //Calculating Total Amount
            int t = item_price * Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString());
            ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTotal)).setText("Rs. " + String.valueOf(t));               
        }               
    }
    });     
    return row;     
}
}
```

activity.menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

activity_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/activity_background">
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/lstItems"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/listview_design"/>           
</RelativeLayout>
```

item_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/listview_design"
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitl"
    style="@style/ListViewHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="@string/itemname"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/img_desp"
    android:src="@drawable/food_item_thumb" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:background="#80FF0000"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:rating="3.5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtPrice"
    style="@style/ListViewBottomText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtTitl"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitl"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:text="@string/price_tag"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtPrice"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ratingBar" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgPlus"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/sqr_plus"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_desp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgMinus"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgPlus"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/sqr_minus"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_desp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtQty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgPlus"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgMinus"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/qty"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        style="@style/ListViewBottomText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:text="@string/total"
        android:textColor="#AC2A2E"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgDiscount"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtTitl"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtTitl"
    android:background="@drawable/label"
    android:contentDescription="@string/img_desp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I think I've provided sufficient information to understand the problem. GeneralHelper is a web service class to get JSON data from server.
Here I want to get order details by the user. But I am facing some problems as following...

1. List Items are not clickable, and when I put event handling code, it is not working
2. How to handle onClick event of ImageButton(imgPlus and (imgMinus) which is placed in ListView item. I tried with the code written in comment in SwipeTabFragment.java, But it is also not working.
3. Last problem is, Tabs are switching very well when we swipe left or right, but if we click on tabs, then not able to switch.

Please help me to solve above problems or any one of them. Thank You!

Comment: You have to Inflate a LinearLayout Instead of ListView to click the event of "+" and "-"

Comment: And put this code in onTabSelected() function:

viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

Comment: Thanks @AvishekDas . You resolved my 3rd problem. Tabs are working good.

Comment: Please use LinearLayout instead of using ListView.

Comment: Can you please provide some more details, how to inflate linear layout? Or give me any link if you have...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution of two problems. That are...

2. How to handle onClick event of ImageButton(imgPlus and imgMinus) which is placed in ListView item. I tried with the code written in comment in SwipeTabFragment.java, But it is also not working.

**Solution :** 
I am handling onclick event in ItemListAdapter.java that is working fine. Below is the code of this file. That may be helpful for others.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class ItemListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> { 
static int grand_total;
private final Activity context; 
private final String title[];
private final String price[];
private final String discount[];    
public ItemListAdapter(Activity context, String[] title, String[] price, String[] discount) {
    super(context, R.layout.item_list, title);
    this.context = context;
    this.title = title;
    this.price = price;
    this.discount = discount;
}       
@SuppressLint({ "ViewHolder", "InflateParams" })
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    final View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null,true);       
    ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitl)).setText(title[position]);
    final int item_price = Integer.parseInt(price[position]);
    ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice)).setText(price[position] + " Rs. Each");
    ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtDiscount)).setText(discount[position] + "%");
    RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) row.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
    stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(row.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);         
    //Increasing Quantity
    row.findViewById(R.id.imgPlus).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView qty = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
            qty.setText(String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString()))+1));
            if (Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString()) > 0) {               
                //Calculating Total Amount
                int t = item_price * Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString());
                ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTotal)).setText("Rs. " + String.valueOf(t));                   
            }
        }
    });     
    //Decreasing Quantity       
    row.findViewById(R.id.imgMinus).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView qty = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
            if (Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString()) > 0) {                   
                qty.setText(String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString()))-1));
                //Calculating Total Amount
                int t = item_price * Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString());
                ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTotal)).setText("Rs. " + String.valueOf(t));               
            }               
        }
    });     
    return row;     
}
}
```

3. Tabs are switching very well when we swipe left or right, but if we click on tabs, then not able to switch.

**Solution :** I simply put the following line in the onTabSelected() and make the tabs working. This was suggested by @AvishekDas. Again Thanks for this.

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {        
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}
```

> But I'm still finding problem 1. My listView is not clickable. If any of you have solution then please post. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How to use LinearLayout:

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

prompts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Type Your Name : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextDialogUserInput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />

</EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutbg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/num"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/del"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="REMOVE" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.bean.FriendBean;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private LinearLayout mList;
private ArrayList<FriendBean> arr = new ArrayList<FriendBean>();
int loader = R.drawable.loader;
int i;
String val;

// public LayoutInflater inflater;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);

    final ImageLoader img = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(
                "jsonarray.json")));
        String temp;
        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(temp);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close(); // stop reading
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    String myjsonstring = sb.toString();

    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(myjsonstring);
        JSONArray jsonarray = obj.getJSONArray("json");
        Log.e("Length", "" + jsonarray.length());
        for (i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
            String friend_name = jsonObj.getString("friend_name");
            String friend_phone = jsonObj.getString("friend_phone");
            String url = jsonObj.getString("image_url");
            FriendBean bean = new FriendBean(url, friend_name, friend_phone);
            arr.add(bean);
            Log.e("u", url);
            Log.e("friend_name", friend_name);
            Log.e("friend_phone", friend_phone);

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

            final ImageView im = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
            final TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            final TextView t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.num);
            final Button del = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.del);
            img.DisplayImage(url, loader, im);
            t1.setText(friend_name);
            t2.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            mList.addView(v);

            t1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
                    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            MainActivity.this);

                    // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
                    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                    final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                            .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

                    userInput.setText(t1.getText().toString());

                    // set dialog message
                    alertDialogBuilder
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {
                                            // get user input and set it to
                                            // result
                                            // edit text
                                            int f = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText()
                                                    .toString());
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                    "Position " + f, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                    .show();
                                            val = userInput.getText().toString();
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                    val, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            t1.setText(val);
                                            // mList.addView(v1);
                                            del.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated
                                                    // method
                                                    // stub
                                                    Toast.makeText(
                                                            getApplicationContext(),
                                                            "Previously "
                                                                    + mList.getChildCount(),
                                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    int f = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText()
                                                            .toString());
                                                    mList.removeViewAt(f);
                                                    Toast.makeText(
                                                            getApplicationContext(),
                                                            "Position "
                                                                    + t1.getText().toString(),
                                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    myFunction(mList);

                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    })
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });

                    // create alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();
                    Log.e("MSG", "HI");
                }
            });

            del.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Previously " + mList.getChildCount(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    int f = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText().toString());
                    mList.removeViewAt(f);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position " + f,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    myFunction(mList);
                }
            });

            im.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            t1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return false;
                }
            });

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void myFunction(LinearLayout l) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

    int c = l.getChildCount();
    for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
        v = l.getChildAt(j);
        TextView t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.num);
        t2.setText(String.valueOf(j));
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finally " + c,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```

jsonarray.json (put this on assets folder)

```
{ "json" : [ { "image_url" : "http://www.ogmaconceptions.com/demo/NewsFeed/app_images/twitter_main.png",
    "friend_name" : "Madhumoy",
    "friend_phone" : "123"
  },
  { "image_url" : "http://www.ogmaconceptions.com/demo/NewsFeed/app_images/twitter_main.png",
    "friend_name" : "Sattik",
    "friend_phone" : "123"
  },
  { "image_url" : "http://www.ogmaconceptions.com/demo/NewsFeed/app_images/twitter_main.png",
    "friend_name" : "Koushik",
    "friend_phone" : "123"
  },
  { "image_url" : "http://www.ogmaconceptions.com/demo/NewsFeed/app_images/twitter_main.png",
    "friend_name" : "Himanshu",
    "friend_phone" : "123"
  },
  { "image_url" : "http://www.ogmaconceptions.com/demo/NewsFeed/app_images/twitter_main.png",
    "friend_name" : "Sandy",
    "friend_phone" : "123"
  }
] }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.customlist"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.customlist.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

FriendBean.java

```
public class FriendBean {
private String Image;
private String name;
private String ph;

public FriendBean(String Image,String name,String ph){
    this.Image = Image;
    this.name = name;
    this.ph = ph;

}

public String getImage() {
    return Image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    Image = image;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPh() {
    return ph;
}

public void setPh(String ph) {
    this.ph = ph;
}



}
```

Just avoid the ImageLoader class. I expect that you can show a image from an URL. If you can do that then just use your method to show a image from an URL to the im ImageView...

Just create a new project with this files and you will understand this..

Comment: Thanks for response @AvishekDas
But what about ImageLoader and FriendBean Classes? Statements that contain these classes are showing errors because they are not defined anywhere. I don't know about the structure of these classes.

Answer (score 0):

You have intentionally commented ListView's onItemclicklistener inside your `onCreateView`

Uncomment the code

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_items, container, false); 
        list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lstItems);
        initializeFoodItems(category_id);
        list.setAdapter(new ItemListAdapter(context, item_name, price_per_unit));
        //ListView event handling



      list.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener );

        return rootView;        
    }
```

ImageVIew Click

Write this method anywhere

```
 // Item Click Listener for the listview
        OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View container, int position, long id) {
                // Getting the Container Layout of the ListView
                RelativeLayout linearLayoutParent = (RelativeLayout ) container;

                // Getting the inner Linear Layout
                RelativeLayout linearLayoutChild = (RelativeLayout ) linearLayoutParent.getChildAt(1);

                // Getting the Country TextView
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) linearLayoutChild.getChildAt(0);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Image CLicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
```

Comment: @KhanSquare try the updated code. See if you are able to see a Toast Message.

Comment: At rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgPlus).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
It is showing NullPointerException!!

And in toast's context, where you passed "this", I have passed activity's instance

Comment: @KhanSquare yes, It is expected. it will not run like this. let me give you an example

Comment: No effect! Everything is as previous. should I set this itemClickListner to a control? Now I just paste this code and run it.